# New Linked Service (Azure SQL Database) Test connection failed

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm creating New Linked Service that would allow connecting to PaaS DB but the Test Connection is failing. Things I've checked are:

-Firewall on Logical VM for PaaS DB(Relevant IP are in place)

-Connect to PaaS DB via SSMS(It Works)

-Typos

I've used AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime since DB is in the same RG as the Azure DataFactory. Google didn't help much.

Regards

PS: More info can be provided if needed.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you have opened the "Allow access to Azure Service" in firewall setting.
[image]

What's your PSSA DB, single database or managed instance?

**For single database**:

The important thing you need to know that:
[image]

**For managed instance**:

To use [copy data from an Azure SQL Database Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database-managed-insance) that's located in a virtual network, set up a self-hosted integration runtime that can access the database. For more information, [see Self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime).

If you provision your self-hosted integration runtime in the same virtual network as your managed instance, make sure that your integration runtime machine is in a different subnet than your managed instance. If you provision your self-hosted integration runtime in a different virtual network than your managed instance, you can use either a virtual network peering or virtual network to virtual network connection. For more information, see [Connect your application to Azure SQL Database Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-connect-app).

Here an tutorial can helps you: [Azure SQL Managed Instances and Azure Data Factory: a walk-through](https://medium.com/@mauridb/azure-sql-managed-instances-and-azure-data-factory-a-walk-through-bfb93e79ac0c).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon

Turning ON allow access to Azure services did the Magic. It's a Single DB not Managed instance.

Thanks

Comment: Note: Turning on "Allow access to Azure Service" is generally considered terrible security practice. Hopefully Azure comes up with a better solution to this.